# Downsample FLAC file if greater than a certain sample rate?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-conversion, sox

I want to convert a whole bunch of FLAC files to ALAC using a tool like **ffmpeg** or **sox**. This by itself is easy enough with a single command line. However, I want to save disk space by downsampling only those FLAC files with a sampling rate greater than a certain value. So something like:

---

For all of the *.flac files in a given directory...

...if the input file has a sample rate greater than 96kHz, convert to ALAC and downsample to 96kHz (adding the “-ar 96000” flag).

```
ffmpeg -i track.flac -acodec alac -ar 96000 track.m4a
```

...else, simply convert it to ALAC unchanged.

```
ffmpeg -i track.flac -acodec alac track.m4a
```

---

**Can this sample-rate detection be achieved, and if so, what would the script look like to perform the above?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...aaaand figured it out. Here, using **sox** to determine the sample rate, and **ffmpeg** to do the transcode. Stuck it in a **bash** script:

```
for f in *.flac; do

  RATE="$(soxi -r $f)"

  if [ $RATE -gt 96000 ]
  then
    echo Resampling and converting... 
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec alac -ar 96000 -c:v copy "${f%}.m4a";
  else
    echo Converting...
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec alac -c:v copy "${f%}.m4a";
  fi

done
```

The *-c:v copy* flag transfers the album art untouched.

Comment: Remove `-vn` and add  `-c:v copy` to avoid video transcoding.

Comment: Great, thanks! Works perfectly - added to the solution.

Comment: If you want to use `ffprobe` instead of Sox, you could do: `ffprobe "$f" -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_streams | grep sample_rate | cut -d= -f2` or similar.